# Proving existence of efficient PAC learning algorithm without noise info given poly-time algorithm with noise upper bound

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, pac-learning

How would I prove that if there is an efficient algorithm for PAC learning in the presence of classification noise by an algorithm that is given a noise rate upper bound $\eta_0$ ($1/2 > \eta_0 \geq \eta \geq 0$) and whose running time depends polynomially on $1/(1 - 2\eta_0)$, then there is an an efficient algorithm that is given no information about the noise rate and whose running time depends polynomially on $1/(1 - 2\eta)$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I disagree with the Bot. However, do you know that what you're asking to prove is true? Also, you still know $\eta < 1/2$, right?

Comment: @mathworker21 - I saw this problem in the Kearns-Vazarani textbook, but I can't figure out how to solve it. It seems to be a looser bound and I'm not sure how the given assumption helps us prove the looser bound